# Boton (+) en datatable bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap, datatable

Estoy usando datatable de bootstrap 5 y veo que el la pagina oficial aparece un boton de + para ver mas detalle de esa fila, pero no encuentro en la documentacion como implementarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguein ya uso datatable con ese boton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) es una librería externa, no es algo propio de Bootstrap. Puedes ver la documentación oficial en la cual encuentras lo que necesitas:

> La API de DataTables tiene varios métodos para adjuntar filas
> secundarias a una fila principal en DataTable. Esto se puede usar para
> mostrar información adicional sobre una fila, útil para los casos en
> los que desea transmitir más información sobre una fila de la que hay
> espacio en la tabla de host.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente @javdromero, muchas gracias